# change the location of zoom control from wpf extension

Tags: wpf, wpf-extended-toolkit

I have a graph inside zoom control (from WpfExtensions- https://wpfextensions.codeplex.com/) in desktop application. The default location of the control is top left.I want to change the location to bottom left.
Update

Comment: What exactly wpf extension library do you mean? Can you provide some xaml?

Comment: @Sam I've updated the questions.

Comment: "The default location of the control is top left" - do you mean zoom slider and buttons?

Comment: yes I mean zoom slider and buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply setup zooming controls (slider and buttons) position from outside - physically it is just `Border` inside `Canvas` with hard-coded position:

```
Canvas.Left="20"
Canvas.Top="20"
```

And I didn't succeed to replace `ZoomControl` template with new position inside target solution (without modifying `ZoomControl` source code) - it change position but stop working properly.

So the only way (worked for me) is to download source code from codeplex and change position inside WPFExtensions -> Themes -> Generic.xaml (lines 27 and 28) to:

```
Canvas.Left="20"
Canvas.Bottom="20"
```

Then compile and replace WPFExtensions.dll in your solution.